# cut/optimize radacct table (FreeRADIUS)

Tags: mysql, sql, freeradius

I trying to optimize radacct table which grows up to 91628239 rows and growing. I decided cut a oldest part of table and putting it to archive db. I need to:

1. save the auto_increment in radacct
2. make a cut when radius is working
3. leave all rows with active session
4. move all rows with closed session to radacct in archive db

I starting make a procedure for this

```sql
BEGIN
/**
 clean up radacct table procedure
*/

-- create fresh radacct table same as old radacct and same auto_increment value
CREATE TABLE db5.radacct_fresh LIKE db5.radacct;
SELECT @my_auto_increment:=auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='radacct' AND table_schema='db5';
SET @query = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE db5.radacct_fresh auto_increment = ", @my_auto_increment);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- copy active sessions to fresh table
INSERT INTO radacct_fresh SELECT * FROM radacct WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL;

-- move radacct to db5h
SET @query = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE db5.radacct RENAME db5h.radacct_', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I can't stop radius server to make this steps. How can I do this smoothly for radius?
Maybe I'm moving wrong way in this optimization at all?

UPDATE
This script is working for my needs

```sql
/*
clean up radacct table procedure
*/

-- create fresh radacct table same as old radacct and same auto_increment value
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db5.radacct_fresh;
CREATE TABLE db5.radacct_fresh LIKE db5.radacct;

LOCK TABLES db5.radacct WRITE, db5.radacct_fresh WRITE;
-- make auto_increment same as in radacct
SELECT @my_auto_increment:=auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='radacct' AND table_schema='db5';
SET @query = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE db5.radacct_fresh auto_increment = ", @my_auto_increment);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- copy active sessions to fresh table
INSERT INTO db5.radacct_fresh SELECT * FROM radacct WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL;

-- move radacct to db5H
SET @query = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE db5.radacct RENAME db5H.radacct_', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- make fresh table as main
ALTER TABLE db5.radacct_fresh RENAME db5.radacct;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

UPDATE

I've made this scheme for radius

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `archive_radacct`(AST int(11), ASEST int(12), AINOCT bigint(20), AOUTOCT bigint(20), ATERMC varchar(32), ASTD int(12), CIS varchar(50), ASESID varchar(32), UN varchar(64), NASIP int(11))
BEGIN
UPDATE db5.radacct SET
acctstoptime = AST,
acctsessiontime = ASEST,
acctinputoctets = AINOCT,
acctoutputoctets =AOUTOCT,
acctterminatecause =ATERMC,
acctstopdelay =ASTD,
connectinfo_stop = CIS
WHERE acctsessionid = ASESID
AND username = UN
AND nasipaddress = NASIP;

DELETE FROM db5.radacct WHERE
acctsessionid = ASESID
AND username = UN
AND nasipaddress = NASIP;
END
CREATE TRIGGER archive_radacct_row BEFOR DELETE ON db5.radacct FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO db5H.radacct SELECT * FROM db5.radacct WHERE radacctid = OLD.radacctid
END
```

Radius CALL archive radacct when receiving Acct-stop. I'm testing this scheme in one of my production radius server. I'm trying to find out is it more heavy load for DB.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this would be to have a trigger on updates which set `acctstoptime` to a non-NULL value, which move the affected row to a historical table.

FreeRADIUS then continues working with the set of rows in the active table.

Comment: trigger on update didn't work in this case. When you trying to delete row from active table it's give an error.